# Can someone explain the ending of The House on Pine Street?

Tags: ending, the-house-on-pine-street

I really didn't understand the ending of the movie [The House on Pine Street](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4085238/). I don't even know whether there really were supernatural events happening or it was all on her mind. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 6):

This Director/Writer interview would seem to answer your questions

### Was it all in her mind?

No. It's a haunted house. It's not in her mind, [genuinely supernatural](https://youtu.be/YBuqhwH3Px4?t=6m28s) things are happening.

> *"so I could create something that was very specific and real from which to draw once we have it all in front of us. This woman who is pregnant and isn't really sure of how she feels about the baby inside her so **she's not only being terrorized from the outside with in the haunted house itself** but she's being terrorized from the inside as well*

### Why is the ghost there?

The Directors intentionally left the ending (and indeed the whole *reasoning* behind the ghost being stuck in the house) ***[intentionally vague](https://youtu.be/YBuqhwH3Px4?t=6m57s)*** as a way of fighting back against what they see as an annoying tendency in modern ghost-horror films to overexplain why there are ghosts and how to get rid of them.

> *... "nowadays it's just this need
> to sort of pander to the audience to
> give the answer away and so usually
> there's a 'medium' character who comes in
> halfway through and knows everything
> they're just like so smart, and they tell
> you exactly why the ghost is happening
> and exactly how you can solve the
> problem. And it makes it less of a horror
> movie and from then on it's more of
> almost a procedural"*

Answer (score 1):

Though it was left intentionally vague, the ending seemed to indicate that, rather than an entity, the events were the main character's "energies" interacting with the "energies" of the house (the story works off the popular misconception that energy is some kind of nebulous cloud-like thing that can just float around).

The main character deals with an unwanted pregnancy, an unwanted move, a controlling mother, and a husband who seems to make decisions without considering her. As the story progresses, her mother becomes even more controlling, her mother and husband begin making decisions for her without consulting her or caring if she agrees, and everyone in her life seems completely apathetic to what she is experiencing, resulting in the strange instances in the house increasing and becoming more terrifying. In the end, while she speaks to the equally apathetic friend of her mother's, the house's energy manifests again and kills her husband. With her husband dead and the baby born, she is finally able to return to the place she never wanted to leave in the first place.

The explanation (by the mother's friend) was that her hatred of the place caused the energy to do what it did, but it seemed that the pressure to suppress her emotions and "make due" caused or strengthened the occurrences.

That's just my take on it, and the writers clearly meant for there to be no concrete answers.

Answer (score -1):

The House is haunted. The writers and director left it vague so that you will need to decide for yourself why there is a ghost in the house. Is it a ghost, a demon, or just negative energy (which I don't believe)? Negative energy did not throw her husband out the window. I liked the movie, but I did not like the vague ending.

Answer (score -3):

No, the house isn't haunted. The movie ends when the "energies" that have been at odds with the main charactar's "energy" offed her husband as a final way to get her to leave it in peace. The house is shown at the end for what it truly is, just an old house, no ghosts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and provide backup/data/expertise.

Answer (score -3):

The house is not haunted. She is a spoiled brat that has some tendency to escape reality. This is her world and we are in it. Some potential for negative energies but obviously people do not like her and see through her.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and provide backup/data/expertise.

Answer (score -3):

The husband who did not belive his wife's experiences  himself feels it but sadly the supernatural entity causes his demise.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please provide [answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and provide backup/data/expertise.